# It's Money - Think about it?

Tags: riddle

> You will get it within a few seconds.
>   Until I am measured,
>   I am not known.
>   Yet how you miss me,
>   When I have flown!

**What am I?**

Comment: It's money. You said so in the title.

Comment: @mmking Nope its Title , the answer is different !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> time

You will get it within few seconds.

> A few seconds is still time.

Until I am measured, 
I am not known.

> You don't know how much time has passed unless you measure it using a clock.

Yet how you miss me, 
When I have flown!

> You will miss pleasant times when they pass.
>  Also known as: "Time flies when you're having fun."

---

Oh, and for the title:

**Its Money - Think about it?**

> There's the common phrase "Time is money."

Comment: Haven't you heard the phrase "time is money"?

Comment: @randal'thor Oh yeah, I suddenly couldn't remember what it was. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget about the phrase "time flies when you're having fun" as well!

Comment: @BaileyM Nope, didn't know about that one :)

Answer (score 1):

It's

> Money

I got it quickly because

> You said it in the title

You're not known until your value is measured.

I miss you when I

> Spend you, you've gone to fly all across the globe!

Comment: Nope ! Your answer is wrong , thing it have much value then Money!

Comment: Are you English..?

Comment: The title is likely a reference to the common English phrase, "Time is money!"